# Why is the observable sending old values

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

I have created a service which sends a request to the backend and makes the result available to the component via an observable.

```
export class QuestionManagementService {

  questionsArray$: Observable<Result>;
private questionsArraySubject: BehaviorSubject<Result>; //to send list of questions
...
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private helper:HelperService, private bs:WebToBackendInterfaceService, private loaderService:LoaderService) {
    this.questionsArraySubject = new BehaviorSubject<Result>(new Result('initial',{})); //A Subject can act both as an Observable and an Observer
    this.questionsArray$ = this.questionsArraySubject.asObservable(); //create Observable. Other components can subcribe to it now to get notifications/values

...
}

//this method sends the request to network via another `bs` service. The request is sent using `http.post` 

getQuestions(questionFilter:GetQuestionsfilter){
    console.log("In QuestionManagementService: getQuestions");
    let observable:Observable<HttpEvent<any>> = this.bs.getQuestions(questionFilter);
    let subscription:Subscription =  observable.subscribe((ev:HttpEvent<any>)=>{
          if(ev.type === HttpEventType.Response) { //null means that the response wasn't an HttpResponse but probably some internal Rxjs event (eg type 0)
            let response= <HttpResponse<any>>ev;
            console.log("http response received: ",response);
            //should remove the token from storage

            console.log('response body from server: ',ev.body);
            let isResponseStructureOK: boolean = this.helper.validateServerResponseStructure(ev.body);
            if (isResponseStructureOK) {
              console.log("response structure is OK");
              let response: ServerResponseAPI = ev.body;
              let result:string = response.result;
              console.log("result is : " + result);
              /*if result could be success or error*/
              /*additionalInformation is a string and the string contains a valid json which has array of questions
              in format {"questions-list":[{"tag":"some tag1","description":"some description1"},{{"tag":"some tag2","description":"some description2"},...]}
              */

              let message:string = response['additional-info'];
              console.log("message is "+message);

              if(result === "success") {
                let jsonQuestionList: string = response['additional-info'];
                console.log("jsonQuestionList response as string: ", jsonQuestionList);
                //let jsonQuestions: PracticeQuestionsListAPI = JSON.parse(jsonQuestionList);
                //console.log("jsonQuestion array:", jsonQuestions);
                //this.questionsArraySubject.next(jsonQuestions['questions-list']);
                this.questionsArraySubject.next(new Result('success', response["additional-info"]));
              } else {
                this.questionsArraySubject.next(new Result('error', response["additional-info"]));
              }
            }
            else {
              /**
               * If something goes wrong, send error rather than send next with result="error"
               */
              console.log("received incorrect response structure from server: ", ev.body);
              //TODOM - need to change hard coded responses and pick them from a config or global variable.
              this.questionsArraySubject.error(new Result('error',"Invalid response structure from server"));
            }
          }
          else {
            console.log("not response. ignoring");
          }
        },
        (error:ServerResponseAPI)=>{/*web to backend service will send error in ServerResponseAPI format. This is what handleError throws*/
          console.log("got error from the Observable: ",error);
          this.questionsArraySubject.error(new Result('error',error['additional-info']));
        },
        ()=>{ //observable complete
          console.log("observable completed")


        });


  }
}
```

The following component subscribes to this service.

```
export class PraticeQuestionListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
questions: PracticeQuestionsListAPI; //the result from observable will be stored here.
questionListSubscription:Subscription; //reference of the subscription

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("destroying component. unsubscribing");
    this.questionListSubscription.unsubscribe()
  }
//on initialisation, I subscribe to the observable

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("in question list on init. question is ",this.questions);
   ...
    this.questions= new PracticeQuestionsListAPI(new AdditionalPagingInfo("",new PartitionInfo(0,0)),
      []);

 let tagSubscription = this.questionManagementService.getSupportedTags(new TagId("coding"));

    console.log("subscribing to question mgmt service");
    this.questionListSubscription = this.questionManagementService.questionsArray$.subscribe((result:Result)=>{
      console.log('received result from question mgmgt service - array observable',result);
      if(result.result === "success") { //received response from server
        let questionList = JSON.parse(result.additionalInfo) as PracticeQuestionsListAPI;
        console.log("got list of questions value ", questionList);
        this.questions['pagination-info'] = questionList['pagination-info'];
        this.questions['questions-list'] = questionList['questions-list'];
        /*
       0 length of questions-list means no questions.
       this could be response from the server indicating that there are no more questions
         */
        /*
        * the server indicates that there are no more questions by either sending empty question list or by sending
        * 0 values for pagination state and partition info
        */
        if (questionList["questions-list"].length !== 0) { //server has send list of questions
          this.questions['pagination-info']['page-state'] = questionList['pagination-info']['page-state'];
          this.questions['pagination-info']['partition-info'] = questionList['pagination-info']['partition-info'];
          this.questions['questions-list'] = questionList['questions-list'];
          console.log("previous question filter is ",this.questionsFilter);

          this.questionsFilter["pagination-info"]["page-state"]=questionList["pagination-info"]["page-state"];
          this.questionsFilter["pagination-info"]["partition-info"].month=questionList["pagination-info"]["partition-info"].month;
          this.questionsFilter["pagination-info"]["partition-info"].year=questionList["pagination-info"]["partition-info"].year;

          console.log("new question filter is ",this.questionsFilter);
          //TODOM - maybe this assignment below was causing memory leak. So changed this as above
          //this.questionsFilter['pagination-info'] = questionList['pagination-info'];
          this.lastPage = false; //the server indicates that there are no more questions by sending these values (no paging state and no partition info)
          if (this.questions['pagination-info']['page-state'].length == 0 &&
            this.questions['pagination-info']['partition-info'].year == 0 &&
            this.questions['pagination-info']['partition-info'].month == 0) {
            this.lastPage = true;
          } else {//if the list is empty then there are no (more) questions for the selected tag
            this.lastPage = false;

          }
        } else {
          this.lastPage = true; //Don't show next button if there are no questions.
          this.showDialog(new PracticeQuestionListContext("Reached end of the search. No more results available", new PracticeQuestionListAdditionalInfo()));
        }
      } else {
        //TODOM - I should probably display the error in case there is an error from the server
        console.log("ignoring value");
      }
    },
    (err:Result)=>{
        console.log("received error from QuestionArray observable",err);
        //TODOM - probably should change the name of DialogContext to Component specific additional context
        this.showDialog(new PracticeQuestionListContext(err.additionalInfo,new PracticeQuestionListAdditionalInfo()));
      },
      ()=>{
      console.log("question mgmt service, questionarray observable completed.");
      });
  }
}
```

The issue I am facing is that if I visit the component for the first time, I get the values from the observable after making some selections in the UI (expected behavior). Then i visit the home page of the application, the component gets destroyed (again, expected behavior). Then if I visit the component again, the observable sends the old values (from the first visit) even when I have not made any UI selections.

Why is the observable sending old values and how can I stop it from doing that? I have created another question in `SO` with pictures which might explain the scenario better

[angular component is retaining old value maybe because the observable is resending past data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103125/angular-component-is-retaining-old-value-maybe-because-the-observable-is-resendi)

Comment: It looks like the observable is in the service, and is a `BehaviorSubject`.  Docs [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject).  Note in the docs where it says "emits it's current value whenever it is subscribed to".  On the first creation, your component causes this Observable to be populated.  However, because the Observable lives in the service, it is not destroyed or cleared when your component is, so when your component is created for the second time and subscribes to that same BehaviourSubject again, it will get the old value.

Comment: Because you have made the `BehaviorSubject` itself private, the solution to this is a little more tricky.  One way to approach it is to create a new method in your service which puts a new (blank) value into the BehaviorSubject, and then call that service method in the `ngOnDestroy()` method of your component.  The key is to let your component clear the value on destroy so that it doesn't show up the next time your component is created.

Comment: Thanks dmcgrandle. Another option I am considering is to use `publish`. This tutorial (http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) explains well the behavior of different types of Observables. It says similar thing about `BehaviorSubject`. It also mentions of `PublishBehavior` which doesn't seem to emit past values. In `rxjs`, an `Observable` has `publish` and there is a `ConnectableBehavior` and `connect` methods but I am struggling to figure out how to use them (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/observable/ConnectableObservable.js~ConnectableObservable.html)